# Arm template nested template and dependsON

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

Does the Arm template dependsOn function work differently for nested templates?

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "location": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "eastus2",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Location for all resources."
        }
      },
      "appBaseName": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Name of the application. Used in the name of resources."
        },
        "minLength": 5,
        "maxLength": 12  
      }    
    },
    "variables": {
      "ResourceGroupName": "[concat(parameters('appBaseName'), '-rg')]",
      "storageAccountName": "[tolower(concat('stg',parameters('appBaseName')))]",
      "WebAppName": "[concat(parameters('appBaseName'), '-web')]",
      "AppServicePlanName": "[concat(parameters('appBaseName'), '-ASP')]"
    },
    "resources": [
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
        "apiVersion": "2019-10-01",
        "name": "[variables('ResourceGroupName')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "properties": {}
      },        
      {
        "name": "nesteddeploymentstorage",
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
        "resourceGroup": "[variables('ResourceGroupName')]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups/', variables('ResourceGroupName'))]"            

        ],       
        "properties": {
          "mode": "Incremental",
          "template": {
            "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
            "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
            "parameters": {
            },
            "variables": {},
            "resources": [
                {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
                    "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
                    "name": "[variables('storageAccountName')]",
                    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                    "sku": {
                        "name": "Standard_LRS",
                        "tier": "Standard"
                    },
                    "kind": "StorageV2",
                    "properties": {
                        "accessTier": "Hot"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "[variables('AppServicePlanName')]",
                    "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
                    "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
                    "kind": "functionapp",
                    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                    "tags": {},
                    "dependsOn": [                   


                    ],
                    "properties": {
                    "name": "[variables('AppServicePlanName')]",
                    "perSiteScaling": false,
                    "reserved": false,
                    "targetWorkerCount": 0,
                    "targetWorkerSizeId": 0
                    },
                    "sku": {
                        "name": "Y1",
                        "tier": "Dynamic",
                        "size": "Y1",
                        "family": "Y",
                        "capacity": 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "[variables('WebAppName')]",
                    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
                    "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
                    "kind": "functionapp",
                    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('storageAccountName'))]",
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', variables('AppServicePlanName'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                    "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', variables('AppServicePlanName'))]",
                    "reserved": false,
                    "siteConfig": {
                        "use32BitWorkerProcess": false,
                        "appSettings": [

                        ]
                    },
                    "clientAffinityEnabled": false,
                    "clientCertEnabled": false,
                    "hostNamesDisabled": false,
                    "containerSize": 1536,
                    "dailyMemoryTimeQuota": 0,
                    "httpsOnly": false
                    },
                    "resources": []
                }                              

            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "outputs": {}
  }
```

I've tried the following combinations and they all fail

```
                        "[resourceId(subscription().subscriptionId, variables('ResourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName'))]",
                        "[resourceId(variables('ResourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName'))]",
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName'))]"
```

Can I not use variables with the resourceId in a deployment template?  Are there any limitations or tricks I should have to worry about?  Does it have to be in plain text and not params or vars?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/linked-templates